# Are there ARM64 equivalents for x86-64 SSE2 integer SIMD GCC built-in functions?

Tags: gcc, x86, simd, arm64, neon

Im trying to use an AMM-Algorithm (approximate-matrix-multiplication; on Apple's M1), which is fully based on speed and uses the x86 built-in functions listed below. Since using a VM for x86 slows down several crucial processes in the algorithm, I was wondering if there is another way to run it on ARM64.

I also could not find a fitting documentation for the ARM64 built-in functions, which could eventually help mapping some of the x86-64 instructions.

Used built-in functions:

```
__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si
__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si
__builtin_ia32_packsswb
__builtin_ia32_packssdw
__builtin_ia32_packuswb
__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw
__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd
__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq
__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw
__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd
__builtin_ia32_punpckldq
__builtin_ia32_paddb
__builtin_ia32_paddw
__builtin_ia32_paddd
```

Comment: Obviously not literally use those functions like you asked for in the title, but you could use equivalent ARM64 SIMD builtins.  `paddb/w/d` of course have direct equivalents, and I think the unpack (interleave) instructions, but I'm not sure about the saturating pack instructions.  Do you actually need their saturation behaviour, or would truncation work for your use-case?

Comment: Normally you'd use intrinsics instead of the raw GCC builtin functions, but see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-C-Language-Extensions-_0028ACLE_0029.html Also https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102467/0100/Why-Neon-Intrinsics- re intrinsics an `#include <arm_neon.h>`.  GCC provides a version of that header, with the intrinsics API implemented using ARM `__builtin_aarch64_...` GCC builtins.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the helpful response! I definitely need their saturation behavior. Are you aware of any documentation comparing both build-ins, which would allow the mapping-process for a beginner like me?

Comment: Not from the raw builtins, but https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde has portable implementations of `immintrin.h` Intel intrinsics like `_mm_packs_epi16` (which most real code should be using instead of GNU C builtins).

Comment: Oh good, turns out ARM does have narrowing with saturation with instructions like `vqmovn` (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/neon-instructions/vqmovn-and-vqmovun), so SIMDe can efficiently emulate `pack` instructions.  Err, that's AArch32, not 64, but probably there's an equivalent AArch64 instruction.

Comment: For AArch64, I think the appropriate instruction for saturating narrow is [`sqxtn / sqxtn2`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100076/0100/a64-instruction-set-reference/a64-simd-vector-instructions/sqxtn--sqxtn2--vector-?lang=en).  Corresponding intrinsics seem to be `vqmovn_s16, vqmovn_high_s16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd use intrinsics instead of the raw GCC builtin functions, but see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-C-Language-Extensions-_0028ACLE_0029.html.  The `__builtin_arm_...` and `__builtin_aarch64_...` functions like `__builtin_aarch64_saddl2v16qi` don't seem to be documented in the GCC manual the way the x86 ones are, just another sign they're not intended for direct use.

See also https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102467/0100/Why-Neon-Intrinsics- re intrinsics and `#include <arm_neon.h>`. GCC provides a version of that header, with the documented intrinsics API implemented using `__builtin_aarch64_...` GCC builtins.

---

As far as portability libraries, AFAIK not from the raw builtins, but **SIMDe (https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde) has portable implementations of `immintrin.h` Intel intrinsics like `_mm_packs_epi16`**.  Most code should be using that API instead of GNU C builtins, unless you're using GNU C native vectors (`__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` for portable SIMD without any ISA-specific stuff.  But that's not viable when you want to take advantage of special shuffles and stuff.

And yes, ARM does have narrowing with saturation with instructions like `vqmovn` (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/neon-instructions/vqmovn-and-vqmovun), so SIMDe can efficiently emulate pack instructions. That's AArch32, not 64, but hopefully there's an equivalent AArch64 instruction.